# Correctly parse returned array from PayPal IPN

Tags: php, paypal-ipn

I'm experiencing a few issues with my PHP custom Paypal IPN script due to not quite knowing how to handle and process arrays for carts containing multiple items.

What I'm trying to achieve is that for each product, a POST call is made back to the server to decrement the stock count for that product, using its unique ID.

Paypal IPN posts the item numbers back as `item_number_1`, `item_number_2`, `item_number_3`, etc, I can get the data with:

```
$id_exp = $_POST['/^item_number(\d*)$/'];
$qty_exp = $_POST['/^quantity(\d*)$/'];
```

What I need to do is make `$id_exp` an array, and run a `file_get_contents` for each product to POST to a URL with the ID, and QTY, is this achievable?

In a nutshell, the end result would be that the IPN script accesses my stock listener (and using GETs here for demonstration only): `http://www.site.com/listener?prod_id=12345&decrement=3`

Update: I've got the array of item IDs printing correctly now, as `123,456,789`, stored in a var called `$id_string` and am now trying to run the following for each ID in the array:

```
foreach ($id_string as $value){
        $url = 'http://myserver.com';
        $data = array('product_id' => $value, 're_stock' => 'true');
        $get = array();

            foreach($data as $k => $v){
            $post[] = $k . '=' . urlencode($v);
            }

            $post = implode('&', $post);

            $opts = array('http' =>
            array(
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'content' => $post
            )
            );

        $context = stream_context_create($opts);

        file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

    }
```

Nothing is happening, however. Any feedback appreciated at this stage.

Comment: I dont like this approach, you should have stored the items ordered on your site in a db,  so all you need back from payapl is conformation of payment, then you extract the product ids from your db to decrees the quantities in your IPN listener script

Comment: @Dagon Thanks for your feedback. All values are stored in a db. This is why I am indeed extracting the product IDs in the IPN and triggering a stock decrement.

Comment: if stored in the db then the specifics of what paypal returns, other than amount paid, is irrelevant. They are a payment gateway they shouldn't be any more involved than absolutely necessary

Comment: Thanks @Dagon for your opinion. In addition to updating the stock in the db, there are a large number of other useful functions I can run based on the returned IDs. It makes sense to build functions into the IPN listener, and I'm not sure what you're trying to suggest here. Thank you for your input though.

Comment: The point is you don't want to rely on the retuned id's you want to get one "transaction" id and the amount, everything else should be handled in house. They are the payment gateway, and should not be part of this process. if you ever change to another gateway, you wont get anything back other than a single transaction id. most don't allow custom data passed, it's not their role.

Comment: Thanks mate, but there's really no harm in using the functions that are provided by Paypal. It speeds things up for me and allows for some seriously cool developer options. It also allows me to get away with fewer assets. I probably wouldn't use a different gateway unless Paypal went bust. In any case, again, thanks for your opinion.

Comment: you  are relying on a third party passing back data *you already have*, it just makes no sense. it should make things slower, and shouldn't add any functionality.

Comment: But it doesn't, in fact it reduces the footprint of sales on my systems substantially. I imagine that this functionality is built into Paypal for a reason, and that developers shouldn't be shamed for making use of it. The fact that Paypal pings this data to my system is incredibly helpful. You take the high road, I take the low road ;)

Comment: we cant possibly be talking about the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$id_exp = array();

foreach (preg_grep('~^item_number[0-9]+$~', array_keys($_POST)) as $key)
{
    $id_exp[preg_replace('~^item_number([0-9]+)$~', '$1', $key)] = $_POST[$key];
}

print_r($id_exp);
```